# Behat testing in laravel with javascript - not using test environment

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, selenium, behat

I have a Laravel 5 project using Behat for acceptance testing. I'm also running this in a Homestead Vagrant box.

I have a page in my site that uses Javascript, and I'm using the Selenim2 driver with phantom js. Selenium seems to be working fine. The problem is when I run my test it uses the development database instead of the testing one. Here's my `.env.behat` file:

```
APP_ENV=acceptance
APP_DEBUG=true

DB_TYPE=sqlite
DB_PATH=acceptance.sqlite
```

And here is my `behat.yml` file

```
default:
    extensions:
        Laracasts\Behat: ~
#            env_path: .env.behat
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            default_session: laravel
            laravel: ~
            javascript_session: selenium2
            base_url: http://127.0.0.1/
            selenium2:
                wd_host: "http://localhost:8643/wd/hub"
            selenium2: ~
```

When I run scenario that doesn't use javascript it uses my test database (as specified in the `.env.behat` file.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables set in the command line are not visible by your web server as it runs in a separate process.

You could do either of the following:

- Set up a test environment in a separate test front controller.
- Set up a test environment in a separate test virtual host.

In both cases you'll need to update the `base_url` in `behat.yml`:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://127.0.0.1/app_test.php
```

Answer (score 1):

To preserve Behat's testing environment when testing Javascript applications, you can use [BehatLaravelJs](https://github.com/sepehr/behat-laravel-js) package as a companion to Behat's Laravel extension.

Besides preserving the environment, it also addresses other limitations like authentication and database transactions when testing Javascript apps using a browser emulator.